# OpenLayers Marker disappears when zooming further than 1 and 2

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have downloaded the libraries (locally into my project) required to use OpenLayers map.
The problem is that after creating the map and creating an overlay for the marker to show on the map it will not show unless you have zoom placed on either "zoom: 1 or zoom: 2".
This is my current code for my map:

```
<div class="map" id="map"></div>
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            var view = new ol.View({
                                                projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                                                center: [-286.2521159648896, 15.60063485072961],
                                                maxZoom: 23,
                                                zoom: 16
                                            });

                                            var OSM = new ol.layer.Tile({
                                                title: 'OSM',
                                                type: 'base',
                                                visible: true,
                                                source: new ol.source.OSM()
                                            });

                                            var satellite = new ol.layer.Tile({
                                            title: 'Satellite',
                                            type: 'base',
                                            visible: true,
                                            source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                                                    attributions: ['Powered by Esri',
                                                        'Source: Esri, DigitalGlobe, GeoEye, Earthstar Geographics, CNES/Airbus DS, USDA, USGS, AeroGRID, IGN, and the GIS User Community'
                                                    ],
                                                    attributionsCollapsible: false,
                                                    url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
                                                    maxZoom: 23
                                                })
                                            });

                                            var base_maps = new ol.layer.Group({
                                                title: 'Base Maps',
                                                layers: [OSM, satellite]
                                            })

                                            var map = new ol.Map({
                                                target: 'map',
                                                view: view
                                            });

                                            map.addLayer(base_maps);

                                            var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
                                                activationMode: 'click',
                                                startActive: true,
                                                tipLabel: 'Layers',
                                                groupSelectStyle: 'children',
                                                collapseTipLabel: 'Collapse Layer'
                                            });
                                            map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
                                            layerSwitcher.renderPanel();

                                            var marker = new ol.Feature({
                                                geometry: new ol.geom.Point([-286.2521159648896,15.60063485072961]),
                                                type: 'SAM',
                                                name: 'SAM'
                                            });
                                            var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                                                title: 'POI',
                                                source: new ol.source.Vector({
                                                    features: [marker]
                                                })
                                            })
                                            map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
                                            layerSwitcher.renderPanel();
                                        </script>
```

Can someone please show me how to add a marker on my map which is not disappear no matter what zoom level I have scrolled or hard coded it at.

Comment: If you are specifying vector features outside the -180 to +180 degree range you should specify `wrapX: false` in the vector source options.  Or you could replace -286.2521159648896 with +73.7478840351104

Comment: Replacing the numbers has solved my issue, but just out of interest how do I add wrapX: false inside the vector source options? Is this how you would do it?
source: new ol.source.Vector({
features: [marker],
wrapX: false,
})